# QGIS Modeler: Where is output from algorithm 'Set style for vector layer'?

Tags: qgis, qgis-modeler

I am writing a model that takes a polygon shapefile as input, converts it to polylines, explodes it to individual lines and finally applies a (tested) style, khLineLength1.qml, which labels each line with its length.

[image: [png]]

Here is the log:

```
Algorithm Polygon_Sides starting...
Prepare algorithm: QGISPOLYGONSTOLINES_1
Running Polygons to lines [1/3]
Parameters: INPUT =C:/Users/DAZ/QGIS_maps/Kaihu/epsg3706/routes_PG.shp
Converting outputs
OK. Execution took 0.187 ms (1 outputs).
Prepare algorithm: QGISEXPLODELINES_1
Running Explode lines [2/3]
Parameters: INPUT =C:\Users\DAZ\AppData\Local\Temp\processing\98fbdd36b519415f9e9bc25e9939916d\OUTPUT.shp
Converting outputs
OK. Execution took 0.234 ms (1 outputs).
Prepare algorithm: QGISSETSTYLEFORVECTORLAYER_1
Running Set style for vector layer [3/3]
Parameters: INPUT =C:\Users\DAZ\AppData\Local\Temp\processing\140dc16954394bd58455470538e300e9\OUTPUT.shp, STYLE =khLineLength1.qml
Converting outputs
OK. Execution took 0.123 ms (1 outputs).
Model processed ok. Executed 3 algorithms total
Converting outputs
Loading resulting layers
Algorithm Polygon_Sides finished
```

According to this
https://docs.qgis.org/2.6/en/docs/user_manual/processing_algs/qgis/vector_general_tools/setstyleforvectorlayer.html
 the **Set style for vector layer** algorithm should have a definable output *Styled layer*. The modeling dialog is allowing me to define the parameters *Vector layer* and *Style file* but that is all.

To clarify: In the modeler, for example, when I edit the Explode lines  algorithm, I see a title **Output layer** and beneath it a box with the hint **[Enter name if this is a final result]**. I do not see this for the styling algorithm and this seems to 'dead-end' the event sequence, preventing rendering and disallowing further styling and the successful execution of any subsequent algorithm.

This is a 'first experience' with the Modeler. Apart from 'little grey cells', what am I missing here?

Supplementary diagram
[image: Supplementary diagram]

Comment: Ehm, what happens if you add another processing tool?  You should be able to use the styled layer as an input.

Comment: Thank-you, I agree (but cannot achieve), and when I add another algorithm, I am sure to specify its input as **'Styled layer' from algorithm 'Set style for vector layer'**!

So for example, running the same styling algorithm twice in succession, the log output additional to the above looks like this:

`Prepare algorithm: QGISSETSTYLEFORVECTORLAYER_2  <br>
Running Set style TWO [4/4]  <br/>
Parameters: INPUT =None, STYLE =khLineLength1.qml  <br>
Failed
Error executing algorithm Set style TWO 'NoneType' object has no attribute '__getitem__' See log for more details`

Comment: Seems to me that **SetVectorStyle.py** is doing everything right when trying to define the output vector:
 `self.addOutput(OutputVector(self.OUTPUT, self.tr('Styled layer'), True))`
so the problem is more likely to be with the modeler editing routines. Running QGIS 2.8.3 & 2.10.1 under Windows 8.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I don't think the docs are very clear on this. From my understanding, the *Set style for vector layer* algorithm **does not create a new output layer**. The end result is the input layer with the style file applied. I believe this is why there is no "output" option for the algorithm.

From the [QGIS 2.8 docs](https://docs.qgis.org/2.8/en/docs/user_manual/processing_algs/qgis/vector_general_tools/setstyleforvectorlayer.html) **and** checking the parameters from the **Python console**, both mention an `Output`:

```
import processing

processing.alghelp("qgis:setstyleforvectorlayer")
ALGORITHM: Set style for vector layer
    INPUT <ParameterVector>
    STYLE <ParameterFile>
    OUTPUT <OutputVector>
```

However, when you check the *Console usage*, you will see that there is no parameter for `Output`:

```
processing.runalg("qgis:setstyleforvectorlayer", input, style)
```

So if you want to add more than one style to a shapefile, you may need to create another set of the same algorithms within your model.

Hope this helps!

Comment: The output is hidden, since there has to be an output...but it is automatically set by the algorithm itself to be equal to the input. This is a strange case, and this algorithm is not a normal one, it's a very peculiar case. That's the reason why the behaviour seems a bit strange...It is more of a hack to add this kind of functionality that is not the normal processing algorithm which takes a layer and produces new stuff

Comment: @VictorOlaya - Thanks buddy, you should post your comment as an answer and I will remove mine. Afterall, it has your name on it :)

Comment: Meanwhile, precariously orbiting planet QGIS, I still cannot render a styled result. [See supplementary diagram above.] I have edited step 'Explode lines' to define a final, output layer 'Exploded_lines'. This (latter) layer, although rendered, is not specifically offered as input to the 'Set style' step. Catch-22?

Comment: Most welcome buddy and hope you get the results you're looking for! And if Victor ever posts an answer here, I would rather you accept his :)