# Defining "Style file" of QGIS modeler process "Set style for raster layer"?

Tags: qgis, qgis-modeler

I want to add "Set style for raster layer" to QGIS processing modeler but I have no clue how I need to define the  "Style file" field. I have a layer style document and I assume, I need to define a path there. However adding the path to the directory works as little as adding only the layer style file-name. Drag'n'drop doesn't work either. Further it's not the gaps in the path, I tried it with a Path without spaces.

It's always the following error in the Log:

[image]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I believe the algorithm is looking for a **File parameter** in order to load the style file. If you add this to your modeler, you can connect the file parameter to the **Set style for raster layer** algorithm:

[image: Model]

When you run your model, you can specify which style to load:

[image: Running model]

---

I think there is a slight bug in the algorithm as when you run it, the style is loaded but the layer is not refreshed. You have to go to the layer's properties and then click *OK* for the style to be applied. You can do a simple fix by editing the script which you can find in (for example):

```
C:/Program Files/QGIS 2.18/apps/qgis/python/plugins/processing/algs/qgis/SetRasterStyle.py
```

And add the following line:

```
layer.triggerRepaint()
```

at the end of the script, directly below `iface.legendInterface().refreshLayerSymbology(layer)`:

```
def processAlgorithm(self, progress):
    filename = self.getParameterValue(self.INPUT)
    layer = dataobjects.getObjectFromUri(filename)

    style = self.getParameterValue(self.STYLE)
    if layer is None:
        dataobjects.load(filename, os.path.basename(filename), style=style)
        self.getOutputFromName(self.OUTPUT).open = False
    else:
        with open(style) as f:
            xml = "".join(f.readlines())
        d = QDomDocument()
        d.setContent(xml)
        n = d.firstChild()
        layer.readSymbology(n, '')
        self.setOutputValue(self.OUTPUT, filename)            
        iface.mapCanvas().refresh()
        iface.legendInterface().refreshLayerSymbology(layer)
        layer.triggerRepaint()
```

Then restart QGIS to update the algorithm.

---

**Edit:**

If the input for the `Set style for raster layer` algorithm is the output of another tool and the raster layer is still not being updated with the style file, it could be a bug in which case you should consider [submitting a bug request](https://hub.qgis.org/projects/quantum-gis).

A possible alternative is to replace the `Set style for raster layer` algorithm (and remove the `File` parameter) with a **Custom script** which loads the style file and refreshes its symbology in the legend interface. You can add a script by going to:

```
Processing Toolbox > Scripts > Tools > Create new script
```

Then use something like:

```
##Example=name
##input=raster

from qgis.utils import iface

layer = processing.getObject(input)

layer.loadNamedStyle('path/to/.qml')
layer.triggerRepaint()
iface.legendInterface().refreshLayerSymbology(layer)
```

Save it in your `/.qgis2/processing/scripts/` directory and load it in your model. Hopefully this might work!

Comment: ok this solved my question. Thank you again for this amazing walk through! I further changed the algorithm and restarted QGIS. But the layer does still not follow the new settings. Maybe you could tell me where exactly I have to add the "set style for raster layer"-tool?  [This](http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/165888/qgis-modeler-where-is-output-from-algorithm-set-style-for-vector-layer) did not really help me.

Comment: @Kevin - Sorry for not responding sooner, are you still having issues?

Comment: no worries. Yes, I still couldn't find it.

Comment: @Kevin - In your modeler, do you have a `Raster layer` parameter, `File` parameter and the `Set style for raster layer` algorithm in your modeler?

Comment: yes, and I already used the raster layer parameter for other tools so I set the "output from tool XYZ" as raster input of the set style tool

Comment: @Kevin - Edited my post to include a possible alternative :)

Comment: Thank you again! I created a new tool, replaced "Example" with my title and set the path to my .qml style. Still, I didn't work (would I have to change anything else, too?). But: I just found that right clicking the model in the processing toolbox shows (beyond others) "edit rendering styles for output". There it is possible to define a style for every output in the model.

Comment: btw: I actually always wrote"@Joseph" in the beginning of my comments but it doesn't appear...

Comment: @Kevin - Most welcome and well done for finding that option! You shouldn't have had to change anything else so it's probably a bug somewhere. I think it disappears because I'm the only one who has commented so I will still receive the notification (although I'm not sure why I can still type it in...)