# QGIS: multiple map measurements

Tags: qgis

[image]

I have a map containing a KML file and a Google satellite imagery layer in QGIS 3.28 LTE. I'm interested in using this to build a map like the in picture below:

[image]

Specifically, I'd like to do multiple measurements, and have these visible on the map. Is it possible to do this in QGIS? I can see the measurements using the measurement tool, but I'm not clear how to save them on the map

Comment: That's accomplished by applying a style to the polygon layer, such as [this one](https://plugins.qgis.org/styles/21/) (import the XML using the symbol manager), the method behind the style is generally explained in [this answer](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/165574/labeling-each-individual-side-of-polygon-in-qgis/314789#314789).

(You might need an additional label to show the area)

Comment: @she_weeds please see https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/477611/adding-uploaded-style-to-kml-file-polygons