# Adding uploaded polygon measurement style to KML file polygons

Tags: qgis, fields-attributes, style, kml

Following up on [QGIS: multiple map measurements](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/477599/qgis-multiple-map-measurements) I want to use a style to convert a kml layer to have measurements on all size, kind of like:

[image]

I'm using  QGIS 3.28 LTE. I started by downloading the style from https://plugins.qgis.org/styles/21/ which is a zip file. I extracted the contained xml file and uploaded it using the setting -> style manager option

If I look in the style manager I now have:

[image]

I've installed the KML tools plugin and used this to create a polygon layer from the kml layer . Next I double clicked on the output polygon label , and added the " Measure feet " Label.

However when I look at the polygon layer, I see:

[image]

The KML file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<kml xmlns="http://www.opengis.net/kml/2.2">
<Document id="root_doc">
<Schema name="2963760840" id="2963760840">
    <SimpleField name="timestamp" type="string"></SimpleField>
    <SimpleField name="begin" type="string"></SimpleField>
    <SimpleField name="end" type="string"></SimpleField>
    <SimpleField name="altitudeMode" type="string"></SimpleField>
    <SimpleField name="tessellate" type="int"></SimpleField>
    <SimpleField name="extrude" type="int"></SimpleField>
    <SimpleField name="visibility" type="int"></SimpleField>
    <SimpleField name="drawOrder" type="int"></SimpleField>
    <SimpleField name="icon" type="string"></SimpleField>
</Schema>
<Folder><name>2963760840</name>
<Placemark>
    <Style><LineStyle><color>ff0000ff</color></LineStyle><PolyStyle><fill>0</fill></PolyStyle></Style>
    <ExtendedData><SchemaData schemaUrl="#2963760840">
        <SimpleData name="tessellate">-1</SimpleData>
        <SimpleData name="extrude">0</SimpleData>
        <SimpleData name="visibility">-1</SimpleData>
    </SchemaData></ExtendedData>
    <Polygon><outerBoundaryIs><LinearRing><coordinates>-88.4317405175818,31.6558800962605 -88.431737410907,31.6559161822374 -88.4317340478576,31.6559522520483 -88.4317304294607,31.65598830298 -88.4317265546618,31.6560243350402 -88.4317224234424,31.6560603464253 -88.4317180368385,31.656096335324 -88.4317133937868,31.6561323008421 -88.4317084963772,31.6561682411606 -88.4317033435555,31.6562041562871 -88.4316979352941,31.6562400435163 -88.4316922726381,31.6562759019385 -88.4316863545151,31.6563117297579 -88.4316801819788,31.6563475269666 -88.4316737560565,31.6563832908516 -88.4316670756934,31.6564190214205 -88.4316601419166,31.6564547159601 -88.4316529536625,31.6564903735763 -88.4316455130305,31.6565259933519 -88.431637818957,31.6565615743927 -88.4316298724689,31.6565971139855 -88.431621673566,31.6566326121303 -88.4316132232843,31.6566680670158 -88.4316045205513,31.6567034768459 -88.4315955664119,31.6567388407112 -88.431586360857,31.6567741577097 -88.4315817286416,31.6567915607419 -88.4311466897599,31.6584809674529 -88.4311356263598,31.658529215528 -88.431124815372,31.6585775059521 -88.431114256788,31.6586258378234 -88.4311039516355,31.658674208429 -88.4310938999238,31.6587226186706 -88.4310841005811,31.6587710667524 -88.431074554662,31.6588195526667 -88.4310652631943,31.6588680737005 -88.4310562240697,31.6589166298692 -88.4310474404426,31.6589652202479 -88.4310389101867,31.6590138430485 -88.4310306343658,31.6590624991651 -88.4310226129532,31.6591111858924 -88.4310148459404,31.6591599023285 -88.4310073343821,31.6592086484659 -88.4310000772153,31.6592574234104 -88.4309930754678,31.6593062244489 -88.430986329149,31.6593550524834 -88.4309798382413,31.6594039057101 -88.4309736027451,31.6594527841292 -88.4309720419662,31.6594653415 -88.4309644366008,31.6595394733955 -88.4309570876343,31.6596136241626 -88.4309499950584,31.6596877928994 -88.4309431588736,31.659761979606 -88.4309365790716,31.6598361833805 -88.4309302545895,31.6599104033289 -88.4309241875368,31.6599846394358 -88.4309183768417,31.6600588899053 -88.4309128225048,31.6601331547375 -88.4309075245268,31.6602074339324 -88.4309024839445,31.6602817256786 -88.4308976996953,31.6603560290821 -88.4308931717888,31.6604303450447 -88.4308889012709,31.660504672657 -88.43088488707,31.6605790101229 -88.4308831265363,31.6606132013205 -88.430880160709,31.6606753008115 -88.4308774511835,31.6607374083529 -88.4308749990237,31.6607995248388 -88.4308728042029,31.6608616475637 -88.4308708656675,31.6609237765354 -88.4308691844632,31.6609859108443 -88.4308677605907,31.6610480504906 -88.4308665929691,31.6611101927763 -88.4308656826711,31.6611723394975 -88.4308650296705,31.6612344879487 -88.430864901764,31.6612506351474 -88.4326782034786,31.6612204116202 -88.432897502907,31.6542440681409 -88.4317454858576,31.6541186481987 -88.4317646239949,31.6548099837846 -88.431765521614,31.65484436124 -88.4317663085529,31.6548787413071 -88.4317669858568,31.6549131230762 -88.4317675535255,31.6549475065475 -88.4322256604991,31.6549477172071 -88.4321986103415,31.6558080866836 -88.4317459607727,31.6558078776201 -88.4317433668281,31.6558439941254 -88.4317405175818,31.6558800962605</coordinates></LinearRing></outerBoundaryIs></Polygon>
</Placemark>
</Folder>
</Document></kml>
```

I don't see any measurements. What am I doing wrong?

Edit1: Regarding: "Select a projected CRS with feet as unit (as we don't know where in the world is your area of interest we can't suggest any, if you have other data in the same area that use a projected CRS in feet you are probably safe using the same…)" -

I'm working in Alabama, but the crs systems from there use meters. At random I picked 1 from New Mexico which had feet as the units. Does this matter?

[image]

[image]

I'm not sure what to do here.

Comment: What CRS is your layer in - does it use feet for units? If it's in WGS84 (EPSG:4326) or Web Mercator (EPSG:3857) the measurements will not show up if you use the Measure Feet symbol, due to a data-defined override in the font marker component of the symbol (which shows the measurements). Use the Measure Meters symbol for meter-based CRS. If your layer uses degrees for units change it to an appropriate projected CRS. Your symbol preview in Style Manager looks weird too, but I downloaded the .xml fresh and used it on QGIS 3.28.15 with no problems.,..

Comment: @she_weeds, I am using WGS84 and my base unit for the layer is feet. How do I get this working with feet?

Comment: To clarify, the project CRS is WGS84 (EPSG:4326 - which uses degrees as units) and the layer CRS is something else (definitely using feet as units in Layer Properties  > Information > Coordinate Reference System > Units)? I still seem to be able to get that to work on QGIS with the Measure Feet symbol... Can you try deleting the symbol and re-importing it from the xml? It doesn't seem right.. Please also be aware though if you use the Measure tool in a WGS84 project you'll get a different result than the measurement on a feet-based layer

Comment: @she_weeds ,  I've added the kml file contents to the question. Can you get this to work for you?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[These style](https://plugins.qgis.org/styles/21/) are designed to not show any measurement if the the layer unit is not in meter or feet (depending on the style you use). As you use KML you are in necessarily in degree so it won't work.

You need to export your data in another format (as KML can only be in degree) and reproject it in projected CSR suitable for measurement in feet in your area. You can do both in a single operation :

Right click on your layer an choose Export>Save Feature As... then in the window that open:

- Choose your export format (if you don't know or don't have a favorite
  the default GeoPackage is a good choice)
- Click on the three dot right to the "file name" input and select a
  location and name to save your new layer
- Select a projected CRS with feet as unit (as we don't know where in
  the world is your area of interest we can't suggest any, if you have
  other data in the same area that use a projected CRS in feet you are
  probably safe using the same…)
- Let all other option as default (you may check the "Add saved file to
  map" at the bottom to automatically load the reprojected layer) and
  click OK
- Style your new layer using using the "Measure Feet" symbol

Comment: please see edit above

Comment: @user1592380 as crs try https://epsg.io/102629 or https://epsg.io/102630 depending on exact location. Set the layer crs and the project crs to the same

Comment: Thank you @J.R, you got it working!